# Circular ImageView comes out as diamond

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make my imageView a circle, but it keeps coming out as a diamond. I thought this code would work but it's not:

```
profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.width / 2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Your image view's height and width should be the same. then it will look like as circle

Comment: they are the same though and I have aspect ratio 1:1 in storyboard.

Comment: Use profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: Hi you don it or not? otherwise i will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your code in

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.width / 2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: stack overflow isn't letting me accept your answer yet but this worked - thank you!

Comment: i also same issue before. i think imageview layout not set proper as autolayout in viewdidload. and you can't accept  because someone mark it with negative votes.

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews will call multiple time to avoid that you can put viewdidload with following way also  {let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                            Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                           profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.width / 2
profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
                        }}

Comment: instead of putting delay and managing such things, please check my answer.. you get actual point where you should put this code.

Comment: Dont use this patches, instead understand the actually what is going inside actually and go via correct way.. instead of going via unusual way

Answer (score 1):

You might not get perfect circle in every device, try changing `2.0` to different near by values for different size devices.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = self.profilePic.frame.size.width / 2.0f;
    self.profilePic.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas for edit suggestion, my first answer here. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Manually implementing `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` by adding it code below to `destinationViewController`.

initialize you `ImageView` as under

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    profiePic = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    profilePic setFrame : CGRectMake ("Set Your Control's Frame here");
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.width / 2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

You will get your desire result.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
profilePicImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicImageView.frame.size.height / 2
profilePicImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
profilePicImageView.clipsToBounds = true
profilePicImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method or `viewDidAppear` method. Actually, as per view lifecycle, the methods are executed in following manner, `init`,`loadView`,`viewDidLoad`,`viewWillAppear`,`viewWillLayoutSubViews`, then autolayout constraints applied(number of autolayout constraints you have, that much time this layout method get called) then, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and at last `viewDidAppear`.

From your question, it looks that you are putting your code in any of the method before autolayout constraints get applied.  That's why, you are not getting proper width of the view and it turns in to diamond instead of circle.